# how to align in container (CSS)?

Tags: css, containers, alignment, navbar

I need to align my navbar to my container. As you can see, I need to align my navbar-brand with the rest of the code.. In the print you can see how it is.. I don't know what should I do.

[see how it is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1t9oL.png)

that is my code:

```
<div class="container">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
            <img src="assets/img/nav_logo.png" width="50" height="50" alt="">
          </a>
          <button class="navbar-toggler custom-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>

          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
              <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Products</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">FAQ</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link dash-button" href="#"><i class="far fa-user"></i> Sign in</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </nav>
        <div class="main-text">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
                <h2>This is the title</h2>
                <p>some textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome text</p>
                <br>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>

        </div>
```

Comment: Please, also post your css so we can have a look on how you're building your navbar style

Answer (score 0):

**It's hard to say without seeing the CSS that's involved**, but two common situations are:

1. `nav_logo.png` includes transparent space on either side of the image
2. The image doesn't have extra transparent space, but `<a class="navbar-brand">` has margin or padding applied via CSS

To fix case 1, you can either crop the image in image-editing software to remove the extra transparent space, or (if you can't edit the image) apply a negative `margin-left` with CSS to "pull" the logo to the left like this:

```css
.navbar-brand {
  margin-left: -20px /* whatever value achieves the desired visual effect */
}
```

In case 2, you would add CSS to override the margins and/or padding, like this:

```css
.navbar-brand {
  margin-left: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
}
```